# Drag bootstrap modal within the window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Modal which i need to drag. I tried the following code

```
$("#myModal").draggable({
handle: ".modal-header"
});
```

I am able to drag the modal but if i drag the modal below the window height, it gives a scroll-bar, I don't want a scroll behavior.

Can any one help please..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer Draggable/jQuery UI Documentation : [Example of Draggable containment](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement)

Try this.

Apply class container to the parent div as `<div class="container">`

OR

to body as `<body class="container">` & Set `containment : '.container'` & also set `scroll:false`.

```
$("#myModal").draggable({

handle: ".modal-header",
scroll : false,
containment: '.container'

});
```